# Overflowing parent widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a widget that has a button and whenever that button is pressed, a list opens up underneath it filling in all of the space under the button. I implemented it with a simple `Column`, something like this:

```
class _MyCoolWidgetState extends State<MyCoolWidget> {
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new MyButton(...),
        isPressed ? new Expanded(
          child: new SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: new MyList()
          )
        ) : new Container()
      ]
    )
  }
}
```

This works totally fine in a lot of cases, but not all.

**The problem** I'm having with creating this widget is that if a `MyCoolWidget` is placed inside a `Row` for example with other widgets, lets say other `MyCoolWidget`s, the list is constrained by the width that the `Row` implies on it.
I tried fixing this with an `OverflowBox`, but with no luck unfortunately.

This widget is different from tabs in the sense that they can be placed anywhere in the widget tree and when the button is pressed, the list will fill up all the space under the button even if this means neglecting constraints.

The following image is a representation of what I'm trying to achieve in which "BUTTON1" and "BUTTON2" or both `MyCoolWidget`s in a `Row`:
[image]

**Edit:** Snippet of the actual code

```
class _MyCoolWidgetState extends State<MyCoolWidget> {

  bool isTapped = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new SizedBox(
          height: 20.0,
          width: 55.0,
          child: new Material(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: new InkWell(
              onTap: () => setState(() => isTapped = !isTapped),
              child: new Text("Surprise"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bottomList()
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget comboList() {
    if (isTapped) {
      return new Expanded(
        child: new OverflowBox(
          child: new Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: new ListView( // Random list
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text("ok"),
                new Text("ok"),
                new Text("ok"),
                new Text("ok"),
                new Text("ok"),
                new Text("ok"),
                new Text("ok"),
                new Text("ok"),
                new Text("ok"),
                new Text("ok"),
                new Text("ok"),
                new Text("ok"),
                new Text("ok"),
              ],
            )
          )
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return new Container();
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using it as follows:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(child: new MyCoolWidget()),
        new Expanded(child: new MyCoolWidget()),
      ]
    )
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what the code is actually doing:
[image]

Comment: Can you link a code that is _not_ working ? So that we can reproduce the error ourselves.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Added!

Comment: @RémiRousselet Changed it a little bit again so that you can simply copy paste it to reproduce :)

Comment: Instead of the overflow thing, can you post the "working" code with  buttons included ? Overflow is not the solution.

Comment: @RémiRousselet This it the code I'm using for the widget I'm trying to create, the only difference is that I extracted my button code from a separate class to the `Column` and I created a dummy list. I just have two of these widgets in a row, would it be helpful to add the code for the row?

Comment: That would indeed be helpful

Comment: @RémiRousselet Added it!

Comment: @BramVanbilsen it sort of looks like what you're trying to build is a set of tabs with content for each... is that correct? If that's the case, take a look at TabController and the [tab cookbook](https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/tabs/).

Comment: @rmtmckenzie Not really, the buttons are unaware of each other. They should be "dumb" in the sense that when they are pressed, they display a list overlaying all other widgets. These buttons don't have to be in rows which make them look like tabs.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie Also, these buttons can be placed anywhere in the widget tree. So they can be nested in a container with a width and height of 50.0 but when they are pressed, the list will still fill up everything under the button. They should not be constrained by the other widgets.

Comment: @BramVanbilsen Just to clarify - is what you're trying to do along the lines of making a popup that covers everything and goes from wherever the button is on the screen to the bottom of the screen, while also filling it horizontally, regardless of where the button is on the screen? Would this toggle open/closed when you press the button? And what would you want to happen in the case where the button is very close to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @rmtmckenzie Exactly what you just described! And I guess it is my responsibility to make sure there is enough room at the bottom. There should not be extra checks there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it was clarified that what the OP wants is this:

Making a popup that covers everything and goes from wherever the button is on the screen to the bottom of the screen, while also filling it horizontally, regardless of where the button is on the screen. It would also toggle open/closed when the button is pressed.

There are a few options for how this could be done; the most basic *would* be to use a Dialog & showDialog, except that it has some issues around SafeArea that make that difficult. Also, the OP is asking for the button to toggle rather than pressing anywhere not the dialog (which is what dialog does - either that or blocks touches behind the dialog).

This is a working example of how to do something like this. Full disclaimer - I'm not stating that this is a good thing to do, or even a good way to do it... but it is *a* way to do it.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

// We're extending PopupRoute as it (and ModalRoute) do a lot of things
// that we don't want to have to re-create. Unfortunately ModalRoute also
// adds a modal barrier which we don't want, so we have to do a slightly messy
// workaround for that. And this has a few properties we don't really care about.
class NoBarrierPopupRoute<T> extends PopupRoute<T> {
  NoBarrierPopupRoute({@required this.builder});

  final WidgetBuilder builder;

  @override
  Color barrierColor;

  @override
  bool barrierDismissible = true;

  @override
  String barrierLabel;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return new Builder(builder: builder);
  }

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 100);

  @override
  Iterable<OverlayEntry> createOverlayEntries() sync* {
    // modalRoute creates two overlays - the modal barrier, then the
    // actual one we want that displays our page. We simply don't
    // return the modal barrier.
    // Note that if you want a tap anywhere that isn't the dialog (list)
    // to close it, then you could delete this override.
    yield super.createOverlayEntries().last;
  }

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(
      BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    // if you don't want a transition, remove this and set transitionDuration to 0.
    return new FadeTransition(opacity: new CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: Curves.easeOut), child: child);
  }
}

class PopupButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final WidgetBuilder popupBuilder;

  PopupButton({@required this.text, @required this.popupBuilder});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PopupButtonState();
}

class PopupButtonState extends State<PopupButton> {
  bool _active = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if (_active) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        } else {
          RenderBox renderbox = context.findRenderObject();
          Offset globalCoord = renderbox.localToGlobal(new Offset(0.0, context.size.height));
          setState(() => _active = true);
          Navigator
              .of(context, rootNavigator: true)
              .push(
                new NoBarrierPopupRoute(
                  builder: (context) => new Padding(
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: globalCoord.dy),
                        child: new Builder(builder: widget.popupBuilder),
                      ),
                ),
              )
              .then((val) => setState(() => _active = false));
        }
      },
      child: new Text(widget.text),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new SafeArea(
        child: new Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: new Column(children: [
            new PopupButton(
              text: "one",
              popupBuilder: (context) => new Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
            ),
            new PopupButton(
              text: "two",
              popupBuilder: (context) => new Container(color: Colors.red),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For even more outlandish suggestions, you can take the finding the location part of this and look at [this answer which describes how to create a child that isn't constrained by it's parent's position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49970726/giving-an-absolute-position-to-a-widget-constraint-by-other-widgets/49987933#49987933).

However you end up doing this, it's probably best that the list not to be a direct child of the button as a lot of things in flutter depend on a child's sizing and making it be able to expand to the full screen size could quite easily cause problems.

Comment: This works totally fine! But wouldn't the `OverlayRoute` class be a better fit than `PopupRoute`?

Comment: One more question: what does `yield super.createOverlayEntries().last;` do exactly? It takes the last `OverlayEntry` probably, but is that the overlay displaying my widget? If so is it correct that this will always have 2 `OverlayEntries` at max? One for the modal barrier and one for the actual content/widget?

Comment: PopupRoute is a subclass of ModalRoute, which is a subclass of TransitionRoute, which is a subclass of OverlayRoute. Each of them adds some additional functionality - transitions for TransitionRoute, back button and a few others for ModalRoute, although I could probably have skipped PopupRoute. That's actually one thing I'm not crazy about in Flutter's implementation, how they've sort of tied implementation of routes to a long chain that each implements a few things rather than say a single class with a bunch of mixins. Tldr; you'd have to implement a lot more if you extended OverlayRoute.

Comment: And yeah that part is a bit messy, but ModalRoute should always return 2 overlay entries - the first being the barrier, and the second being what you actually want to display (that will always be last because last is on top ;p). Using yield was just me being lazy, I could have done without sync* and returned a list/other iterable containing just the last element in the super's interable.